# Derived invariance of the Cartan determinant

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

The Cartan matrix $C$ of a finite quiver algebra $A$ with points $e_i$ is defined as the matrix having entries $c_{i,j}=\dim(e_i A e_j)$. The Cartan determinant is defined as the determinant of the Cartan matrix.

> **Question.** Who proved first that the Cartan determinant is an invariant of the derived category of the algebra? Is there a reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that this is one of those things that was essentially well-known to many people before anybody wrote it down, so it will be hard to pin down the first person to prove it.

But the main idea goes back to

*Happel, Dieter*, [**On the derived category of a finite-dimensional algebra**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02564452), Comment. Math. Helv. 62, 339-389 (1987). [ZBL0626.16008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0626.16008).

There Happel considered the bilinear form on $K_0\left(D^b(\text{mod }A)\right)$, for an algebra $A$ of finite global dimension, given by $\left\langle[X],[Y]\right\rangle=\sum_i(-1)^i\dim\text{Hom}(X,Y[i])$. To get the statement about the Cartan determinant just requires the idea of doing the same for $K_0\left(K^b(P_A)\right)$ for an arbitrary finite dimensional algebra, where $K^b(P_A)$ is the triangulated subcategory of $D^b(\text{mod }A)$ consisting of bounded complexes of finitely generated projective modules.

The derived invariance of the Cartan determinant is explicitly stated as Proposition 1.5 in

*Bocian, Rafał; Skowroński, Andrzej*, [**Weakly symmetric algebras of Euclidean type.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2005.2005.580.157), J. Reine Angew. Math. 580, 157-199 (2005). [ZBL1099.16002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1099.16002),

where they credit me with suggesting the proof. But I don't remember doing so, and I suspect it may have been in a conversation at some conference many, many years earlier. I also suspect that I was not the only person at the conference who would have suggested exactly the same proof.

Answer (score 2):

Check out these references:

[$q$-Cartan matrices and combinatorial invariants of derived categories for skewed-gentle algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504547), Christine Bessenrodt (Hannover), Thorsten Holm

[Algebra invariants for finite directed graphs with relations](http://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s54Abessen.ps), Christine Bessenrodt